# CSS3 transition does not work when I add switch between display:none and display: inline-block

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

I want to slide my search box from right to left on the click of search button. The search box should be hidden. The transition works fine when I switch the `margin-right` property from `-220px` to `0px`.

However, when I add the `display: none` or `display: inline-block` property, it does not work. I also tried `visibility` property. It slides, but I want it to slide from the start of the button and not behind the button.

I don't know where I am going wrong.

Please help.
[Please check the jsfiddle here...](http://jsfiddle.net/ftqvhkv7/1/)

```js
$(document).on("click", "#searchtoolbar", function() {
  var hasclass = $("#search").hasClass("searchshow");
  if (!hasclass) {
    $("#search").addClass("searchshow").focus();
  } else {
    $("#search").removeClass("searchshow");
  }
});
```

```css
@import "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";
#inputbar {
  border-color: red;
  list-style: none;
}
#search {
  background: #007F64;
  /*display:none;*/ /*It does not work with the transition when I do this.*/
  visibility: hidden;
  right: 300px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  top: 18px;
  height: 27px;
  width: 177px;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  margin-right: -220px;
  transition: margin-right;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
#search.searchshow {
  border-color: #41A940;
  outline: none;
  margin-right: 100px;
  visibility: visible;
  /* display:inline-block; */ /* The transition does not work if I do so*/
}
#searchtoolbar {
  background: #007F64;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 260px;
  top: 18px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<li id="inputbar">
  <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
</li>
<button id="searchtoolbar" type="submit" aria-label="Search button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transitions on the display: property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331353/transitions-on-the-display-property)

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS transition for any `display` property, including `display:none`

If you need to animate that transition, you will need to manually change whatever property you need to animate first, then set a delay in javascript so you can set it to `display:none` after the CSS transition completes.

Comment: It's not only `display: none`, it's the whole property `display` which is not animatable.

Comment: For a reason, I do not want to do it through javascript. I believe we can make some use of overflow or visibility property. Just not sure how. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As the previous commenter said, `display` can't be animated. What about manipulating the width instead? Here's a working example:

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmakesthings/rgw7vuy9/)

```css
#search {
    /* ... */
    width: 0;
    padding: 8px 0;
    transition: all; /* Width and padding */
    transition-duration: .5s;
    /* ... */
}
#search.searchshow {
    /* ... */
    padding: 8px 4px;
    width: 177px;
    /* ... */
}
```

```js
$(document).on("click", "#searchtoolbar", function() {
  var hasclass = $("#search").hasClass("searchshow");
  if (!hasclass) {
    $("#search").addClass("searchshow").focus();
  } else {
    $("#search").removeClass("searchshow");
  }
});
```

```css
@import "http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";
#inputbar {
  border-color: red;
  list-style: none;
}
#search {
  background: #007F64;
  right: 300px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  border: none;
  top: 18px;
  height: 27px;
  width: 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  transition: all; /* Width and padding */
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
#search.searchshow {
  border-color: #41A940;
  outline: none;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  width: 177px;
}
#searchtoolbar {
  background: #007F64;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 260px;
  top: 18px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<li id="inputbar">
  <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
</li>
<button id="searchtoolbar" type="submit" aria-label="Search button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: It works man! Thanks a lot. However, is there a way to do it through 'overflow:hidden' or through visibility property. I tried a lot. It would be good to know. Thanks again Jack...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate `display` ([read more about animatable properties](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp)) but you can animate the `opacity` property, and [browser support is great](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity).

Although `visibility` is animatable, this isn't really the best way to go from 'hidden' to 'visible' - that property was invented more as an accessibility thing.